# $.inArray does not work in AND < IE 9, any alternative?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have this simple array where I am using $.inArray to check whether a value exits in the array or not.

## Code:

```
var qsParams = { };
qsParams.genders = ["MENS","WOMENS"];
qsParams.colours = [];

 var ele = "MENS";
 if ($.inArray(ele, qsParams.genders) != -1)
 {
    alert("MENS exits in array");
 }
```

## IE 9 Error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected 
jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2 character 14993
```

Any suggestion or solution?

[image]

Comment: $.inArray() should work in IE<9. FYI, following your code, should be: `alert("MENS exits in array");`

Comment: thx for pointing me that as it was typo..

Comment: BTW, check object qsParams.genders, is it the expected result in IE9? Error message suggests it isn't

Comment: ok ...let me check...

Comment: not working... still error.. array is not null as you can see in the updated question...

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle, i'm unable to reproduce your issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P8L9H/   i dont know how to tell jsfiddle to run that in IE7

Comment: using IE7 go to http://jsfiddle.net/P8L9H/show  Still, i don't have any error here using IE10 mode ie7. Even i'm quite sure this is not related to your issue but you should define object without any space: `var qsParams = {};`

Comment: yes, even i think so its not an issue with $.inArray.. BUT somehow i am not able to figure out whats going on... array is perfect and its not going to next line for check..

Comment: Ctrl -> F5? Bet it's cached your js?

Comment: possible... let me try that